# Problem setting fixed frame in Rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am already able to publish the data, in the sense that when i type the rostopic hz -> i get the topic that i am publishing. But have difficulty visualizing the data and moreover, i can't select anything under fixed frame and target frame.there is a global warning saying that is no tf data and that Fixed Frame does not exist. I now know i need to have to a launch file that converts static_transform_publisher from /world to /kinect_depth and set the fixed frame to /kinect_depth.

1)i am not sure where to add this file to?

2. there is a statement args = " 0 0 1.10 -1.57 0 -1.57 /world /kinect_rgb 10"
   what does the 10 stand for and what are the other values(such as 0, 1.1) for?

having those two questions answered, i got a few more to ask( i apologise if the qns are wrong)..

3. what should i type to launch the kinect_camera.
   is it roslaunch kinect_camera kinect_with_tf.launch?
   if so, it is wrong to type roscore only?
4. must u have always have a launch file? can u work without a launch file?

5)is better to use tf::transformbroadcaster or it is better to use just launch file?

Please pardon me for the qns.. i am newbie in ROS, point cloud. Any help would be much appreciated.. thanks...

for env | grep ROS
i get

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/diamondback/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks:/home/user/workspace
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10477/problem-setting-fixed-frame-in-rviz./) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If there is no /tf information, you can for testing just type the frame you are sending in the fixed_frame of rviz.

1. To a launch file that also launches the kinect driver.
2. the 10 is the publishing frequency. The other numbers are: x y z roll pitch yaw. (If you pass 4 parameters for rotation it is interpreted as a quaternion)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-05**:
It is normal to get a "no tf" warning, if you are not publishing tf. You will need to publish tf, e.g. with the static publisher to have tf data. TF data only comes from tf publishers, roslaunch is something totally different.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-05**:
Regarding the testing  by typing the frame you are sending in the fixed_frame of rviz, it didnt work as well.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-05**:
thanks for your help... really appreciate it...

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-05**:
just like to ask something else. i face the global warning of no tf data. Am i right to say there are two ways to solve this problem? One is using the launch file while the other is the tf/transform..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does your RVIZ start in a terminal with the correct environment variables?

```
$env | grep ROS
```

should tell you how they are set in that terminal.
What's the output file of

```
$rosrun tf view_frames
```

Sometimes I have to click on a different field first and wait before I can select the fixed frame.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-07**:
i posted the output...

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-07-05**:
could you post the output of the env variables?

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-05**:
thanks for replying... when i type tf view_frames, i get" no tf data received". and the environment variables seems to be ok.